# Simple modal destroy data after closing doesn't work on mobile browser

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I set up a modal window using simplemodal, but it seems not to work when it comes to closing this window on mobile browser (Android Gingerbead), it just sends back the content to its original position in the DOM. What I want to do is just destroy or hide the content.

Here's my call to simplemodal:

```
$('#parrainage').modal({
        minWidth:800,
        minHeight:490,
        autoResize:true,
        closeHTML:'<span><img src="files/soleil_files/images/close.png" /></span>',
        overlayClose:true,
        onClose: function (dialog) {
            dialog.data.fadeOut('slow', function () {
                dialog.container.hide('slow', function () {
                    dialog.overlay.slideUp('slow', function () {
                        $.modal.close();
                        console.log(dialog.data[0].remove());
                    });
                });
            });


        },persist:true
});
```

Any clue?

Thanks

Comment: can you post a link to a live version?

Comment: here's the url : http://www.soleiletmoi.com/centre-bronzage-lille.html